# Merge global and environment variables

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I need to link specific file in production environment in addition to global linked_files:

My current configs:

deploy.rb

> set :linked_files, ['config/database.yml']

production.rb

> set :linked_files, ['config/database.yml', 'config/email.yml']

Is it possible to add some files in `production.rb` to `linked_files` from `deploy.rb`?

Like this:

production.rb

> set :linked_files, merge('config/email.yml')

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old, but just for the sake of knowledge:

```
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files) | %w{config/unicorn/test.rb }
```

In other words, simply join arrays from global and environment file